# how to get old location from corelocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

locations array last object holds new location, How to get the previous location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create and use a mutable array of previous locations that were updated from previous calls to "`locationManager: didUpdateLocations:`".

[According to the Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidUpdateLocations%3a), the only time that "`locations`" array passed in via the delegate method will have more than one entry will be "If update events were deferred or if multiple events arrived before they could be delivered, the array may contain additional entries."

Comment: In particular, this call will likely only receive multiple locations on iOS6 when running on an iPhone5 or more recent model and when update queuing has been turned on.

Comment: @MichealDautermann Thanks a lot for replying, Please can you clear one more confusion? In Location Awareness guide Apple says: If a location update has already been delivered, you can also get the most recent location data directly from the CLLocationManager object without waiting for a new event to be delivered. I am not getting this. Please help out.

Comment: this sounds like a separate question to me... why not ask a new question with that detail?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Please view my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263392/what-location-manager-is-offering-as-its-recent-value

Answer (score 0):

**Get updated location in this method**

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) 
 {
   guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else { return }         
   print(mostRecentLocation)
 }
```