# What location manager is offering as its recent value

Tags: ios, core-location

I asked a question regarding how to get old location from this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

And I got reply

> You should create and use a mutable array of previous
>   locations that were updated from previous calls to "locationManager:
>   didUpdateLocations:".
>   [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261463/how-to-get-old-location-from-corelocation/16261503?noredirect=1#16261503)

Now I am confused regarding that in [Location Awareness guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) Apple says this:

> If a location update has already been delivered, you can also get the
>   most recent location data directly from the CLLocationManager object
>   without waiting for a new event to be delivered.

I am not getting this point. Please help me out.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I would like to invite you to reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [Apple's documentation for CLLocationManager, you'll see it has a property you can access that's named "`location`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/location).

This property contains the last reported location data.

And whenever new locations gets resolved & reported, that property should presumably be updated.

In general though, you'll want to keep your users up-to-date on the current location via updates passed through the delegate methods.